# Python. Использование циклов со счетчиками и с проверкой списков

Tags: python, циклы, случайные-числа

У меня есть код:

```py
from random import choice

комбинация = ['w', 4, 5, 2, 'a', 8, 3, 9, 7, 6, 'g', 'r', 1, 'y']

my_ticket = []

def random():
    return choice(комбинация)
    
def перебор():
    print("Выигрышная комбинация:")
    for _ in range(4):
        my_ticket.append(random())


    
перебор()
print(my_ticket)
```

У меня дальше есть задача создать цикл, который будет перебирать комбинации, и когда цикл найдет нужную комбинацию (как в `my_ticket`), то он должен остановиться и написать сколько попыток потребовалось, чтобы найти нужную комбинацию.

Я переписал код выше:

```
from random import choice

комбинация = ['w', 4, 5, 2, 'a', 8, 3, 9, 7, 6, 'g', 'r', 1, 'y']

my_ticket = []

my_target = ['a', 4, 5, 'g']

def random():
    return choice(комбинация)
    
def перебор():
    for _ in range(4):
        print(random())


count = 1
def цикл():
        while True:
            for _ in range(4):
                my_ticket.append(random())
            count += 1
            if my_ticket == my_target:
                print(my_ticket)


цикл()
```

но он не работает

Comment: 1) Поместите сюда вашу версию кода с этим циклом. 2) Вы забыли принять ответ за предыдущую задачу. 3) Посмотрите, как надо правильно размещать код в вопросе - с помощью `~~~` в начале и конце (я отредактировал). 4) Название вопроса лучше не копировать с предыдущего, а изменить.

Comment: Вообще-то правильнее не `~~~` обозначать код, а ``` и еще после этого язык кода написать (```python3)

Comment: у меня даже нет идей как использовать цикл сдесь

Comment: @Пушистик, ссылку дайте, пожалуйста, на источник "правильности". Не спорю, но хочу понимать  причину.

Comment: а мне поможете ребята?

Comment: @IRBIS, как бы делал я на вашем имеющемся коде: 1) Завел бы список target_ticket с "нужной" комбинацией, а также счетчик, изначально равный 0. 2) цикл тут - до выполнения условия - `while my_ticket == target_ticket`. И после каждой генерации комбинации увеличивал бы счетчик на 1 (не забывайте очищать список каждый раз). Теперь дерзайте - возвращайтесь с рабочим кодом или с конкретной проблемой. Можете почитать про циклы `while` и про списки. Кстати, если порядок в комбинации не важен, то ещё `sorted` добавьте перед проверкой. Или `set` используйте.

Comment: @Сергей, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: все равно не понимаю как написать цикл

Comment: @Пушистик, за ссылку спасибо, интересно. А вот ```с указанием языка особо ничего не дает при правильной метке языка - подсвечивание автоматически включается. Т.е. можно и так, и так. Но идея понятна, спасибо.

Comment: Если не хватило моего текста, то советую внимательно читать учебник - значит, понимание языка и алгоритмизации далеко от идеала. И задуматься, зачем вы вообще все это пишете. Если научиться - то надо самому делать, если нет, то масса чужих хороших игрушек есть.  На чужих кодах нормально не научиться языку.

Comment: я написал код, но он не работает, посмотрите в вопросе, я отредактировал

Comment: я так понимаю что мне лучше всего как вы и сказали более внимательно читать учебник

Comment: + 1 за свой код. Исправления поместил в ответ. Но учебник да, читайте. Вам понравится при должном тщании. Программировать самому - интересно.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choice


def random(combination):
    return choice(combination)


def enumeration(combination, my_ticket):
    print("Выигрышная комбинация:")
    for _ in range(4):
        my_ticket.append(random(combination))

def run_times(my_ticket, combination):
    count = 0
    while True:
        win_ticket = [random(combination) for i in range(4)]
        if win_ticket == my_ticket:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
    return count, win_ticket


combination = ['w', 4, 5, 2, 'a', 8, 3, 9, 7, 6, 'g', 'r', 1, 'y']
my_ticket = []

enumeration(combination, my_ticket)
print(my_ticket)
solution = run_times(my_ticket, combination)
print(f'Мы получили ваш выигрышный билет {solution[1]}.\nДля нахождения потребовалось {solution[0]} попыток')
```

Comment: а можно цикл написать по другому, без квадратных скобок

Comment: @IRB1S, да, конечно, можете его написать так же, как вы это сделали в функции enumeration, чуть медленнее будет, но ничего страшного

Comment: я все равно не понимаю как писать цикл, я уже запутался

Comment: @IRB1S Полагаю, что вам лучше почитать соответствующую литературу или посмотреть видео с примерами, где это будет наглядно разбираться. Вам нужна была помощь с кодом. Вот, пожалуйста.

Comment: IRB1S, начните с того, что поймите, что именно вам не понятно. Почитайте. Задайте конкретные вопросы. "Квадратные скобки", кстати, называются "генератор списков" (и про него можете почитать).

Comment: @IvanMain, вот именно поэтому и не имеет смысла тут просто писать коды - всё равно не сильно поможет, если это не прямой "сделайте мне домашку", но её делать тоже смысла нет).

Comment: @Сергей, мне нужны баллы), я ведь даже комменты писать не могу

Comment: @IvanMain, найдете более подходящий момент. Но +1 я поставил. А автор, как видите, код сам написал всё же, в конце концов, пусть и с ошибками:-)

Comment: @Сергей спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Ниже исправленный код с комментариями в тексте по каждому исправлению. Изучите внимательно эти темы:
а) области видимости, особенно функции;
б) счетчики (просто на бумажке прикиньте, как они работают);
в) списки (рекомендация моя "не забывайте очищать список каждый раз" была проигнорирована).

```
from random import choice

combination = ['w', 4, 5, 2, 'a', 8, 3, 9, 7, 6, 'g', 'r', 1, 'y']

my_target = ['a', 4, 5, 'g']


def random():
    return choice(combination)


def perebor():
    for _ in range(4):
        print(random())


def cycle():
    # 1) Перенесли счетчик в область видимости функции
    # 2) Начинается он с 0, так как не было еще попыток.
    count = 0
    while True:
        # Обнуляем список каждый раз, или он бесконечно будет расти и не совпадет никогда
        my_ticket = []
        for _ in range(4):
            my_ticket.append(random())
        count += 1
        if my_ticket == my_target:
            # Добавили счетчик на вывод
            print(my_ticket, count)
            # Прервать цикл надо, если совпало, а то без конца будет работать
            break


cycle()
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)